# Backup before demoting a Windows 2003 R2?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller

So i want to demote our good old Windows 2003 R2 DC, which is one of 2 DCs in our system.
I have layed out all the steps (imo) necessary to sucesfully demote the controller.
Before i start i would want to know, how i can backup the DC? If anything goes wrong during the process. And what is generally considered good practice before - during and after the demoting-process?
I'd appreciate your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a good practice, you should have at least 2 DCs (new) not 1.

If you want to demote the old one, do a Windows Backup of both old and new systems and then you can decommission the old one.

Before actually doing it, you should check the following components that are either running or registered:

- Global Catalog
- FSMO Roles
- Bridgehead server
- General server checks
- That you have enterprise admin credentials

To actually demote it:

- On the new domain controller, click Start, and then click Run.
- In Open (or Run), type dcpromo to open the Active Directory Installation Wizard, and then click Next.
- On the Remove Active Directory page, click Next, and then continue to follow the wizard.

Comment: Thanks @Overmind for your quick reply and by "windows-backup" you mean the standard backup programm which comes with windows right?

Comment: Yes, the integrated backup. If the feature is not enabled, you can enable it.

Comment: Thnak you very much :)